# Unable to do overlay with <t:loop> (Tapestry )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay, tapestry

This is my tml code

```
 <t:loop t:source="image" t:value="pojo">    //problem with <t:loop>
    <a rel="#overlay${pojo.id}">
        //image tag here  
     </a>

    <div class="app_overlay" id="overlay${pojo.id}">
           <img width="80" height="60" src="${pojo.url}" />
     </div>
 </t:loop>
```

This is my jquery for overlay

```
    $("a[rel]").overlay({ top: '24%' ,
         mask: { 
           color: '#0f0f0f',
           loadSpeed: 200,
           opacity: 0.9

      },

           closeOnClick: false ,
    });
```

My problem is, without t:loop(i mean with static source) it works perfectly, but if i give this code in t:loop. It doesn't work. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Dumb suggestion here, but did you try adding t:id to it?